# Calculating negative result - Math fail

Tags: android, math, calculator

Good evening!
I never was good at math.
I created a Spinner in which you can select a specific term and based on that it calculates a different result.
Problem now is my result is negative. I think is has to do with the value I assigned to the Strings.

Fragment.java:

```
        List<palwerte> werteListe = new ArrayList<>();
    palwerte wert1 = new palwerte("Nur sitzend oder liegend", 1.2f);
    werteListe.add(wert1);

    palwerte wert2 = new palwerte("Ausschließlich sitzend", 1.4f);
    werteListe.add(wert2);

    palwerte wert3 = new palwerte("Sitzend, aber auch gehend oder stehend", 1.6f);
    werteListe.add(wert3);

    palwerte wert4 = new palwerte("Überwiegend gehend und stehend", 1.8f);
    werteListe.add(wert4);

    palwerte wert5 = new palwerte("Körperlich anstrengende Arbeit", 2.3f);
    werteListe.add(wert5);
```

And here is the Calculator (also inside Fragment.java):

```
            float PAL = spinnerp.getSelectedItemPosition();
            float result3 = result2 * (PAL - 1);
            float result4 = result3 - result2;
            int result5 = Math.round(result4);
            userLeistung.setText(" " + result5);
```

Result2 is already working perfeclty so no problem with that. Only question about the code I posted here. 
and the palwerte.java:

```
public class palwerte {
    private String name;
    private float wert;

    public palwerte(String name, float wert) {
        this.name = name;
        this.wert = wert;
    }

    public String getName() {

        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {

        this.name = name;
    }

    public float getWert() {

        return wert;
    }

    public void setWert(int wert) {

        this.wert = wert;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: why PAL -1 tho? Item 0 would make it negative. If the value is correct, just wrap result5 in Math.abs()

Comment: Because it needs to take the PAL for example from 1.2 first - 1 so it's 0.2 and then multiply it with result 2.

Comment: getSelectedItemPosition() returns the position which starts from 0 to length. What you want is the value, not position. the answer below is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are using the position of the item selected instead of the value.
You have to get the parwerte item from your list. I think this is what you are looking for:

```
int position = spinnerp.getSelectedItemPosition(); 
float PAL = werteListe.get(position).getWert();
float result3 = result2 * (PAL - 1);
float result4 = result3 - result2;
int result5 = Math.round(result4);
userLeistung.setText(" " + result5);
```

Comment: Getting an error in the second line D:, 'local variable werteListe is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final'

Comment: final List<palwerte> werteListe = new ArrayList<>();